# Publishing VS project: Installer requires .NET 4.6.2

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, build-error

I am trying to make a simple Windows Forms app that communicates with Arduino.

As this is my first WinForm application, I am currently stuck on the publish process.

I manage to publish the app with a installer, but, when I open the installer, [it asks for the .NET Framework 4.6.2 to be installed.](http://prntscr.com/emokej)

I tried targeting the .NET 4 version on my project, but the installer keeps requiring the 4.6.2.

Do you know how to solve this? OR is this maybe due to the installer itself needing the 4.6.2 framework?

Thanks,

Comment: look at this link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873130.aspx

Answer (score 1):

did you change the .net version required on the installer project ? if not, you should check your launch conditions (right click your project → vies → launch conditions). There you can right click ".NET Framework" and chose properties. In the properties window you can adjust your .net version required.

I'm assuming you use the installer projects from the "Visual Studio Installer Projects" extension.

Comment: Sorry I explained my self poorly as I lack terms in my vocabulary :)

As I saw from @Muckeypuck 's answer above my problem was with ClickOnce applications where you only deliver a Setup.exe file (or online link) to your end user.